# How to access returned HTML element

Tags: javascript

This function defines an HTML element. `document.getElementById` returns the complete function, not only the h1 element as expected. How I only write what's inside of the two ` (return value).

```
function tokens() {
        return `
        <h1>test</h1>
    `;
}

document.getElementById('tokens').innerHTML = tokens;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```js
document.getElementById('tokens').innerHTML = tokens;
```

to

```js
document.getElementById('tokens').innerHTML = tokens();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function with parentheses `()` in order for it to execute and return the proper output:

```js
document.getElementById('tokens').innerHTML = tokens();
```

Answer (score 1):

You've written `tokens` as if it is a variable. Since you want to run a function, add `()` to `tokens`. That would be `tokens()`.